# How to detect a click anywhere on the document EXCEPT a specific DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onclick, show-hide

I am using Jquery to shown and hide an overlay on the web page.

In my scenario, I am showing an overlay menu and currently close the overlay when an item within the menu is clicked (click event detected and then overlay closed).

```
$('#menu a').click(function(){ $('.overlay').hide(); });
```

Nice and simple!

I now have a requirement that I want to hide the overlay when anywhere on the screen is clicked other than the menu item (for convenience).

Here's an example:

[image]

```
$('.overlay').click(function(){  
  // pseudo code
  if (isDivClicked == false){
     $('.overlay').hide();
  }
});
```

Is there a way to see if the clicked area is the overlay but NOT the div shown (with the menu items).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yeah, what you can do is check if the target is the div. 
you will need to change 
.click(function(event){
    var taget = event.target
}

Comment: Add a event listener and find out if the target is not div and then do the job you want to do

Comment: This is being asked every week. Do some research before posting, guys